# Is the performance of a RAM drive inside a VM comparable to native hardware?

Tags: performance, virtual-machine, ramdisk

If I define a ram drive inside a VM will it behave the same as a ram drive on bare metal (with in reason). I am looking to setup a VM on my KVM node that will run a few games. Yes, one of them is Minecraft... which what I would use the ram drive for.

From the way I see it RAM is RAM but since the hypervisor is in between the VM and baremetal. I imagine it plays some part in the process and may have an impact on the overall performance of the RAM drive.

Is this the case or am I incorrect in my assumptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The impact of hypervisor overhead should be minimal - typically its less then 5% for a VM.

Although the host does intercept and remap memory, this function is now largely done in hardware so its quite efficient.  Have a look [here](https://corensic.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/virtual-machines-virtualizing-virtual-memory/), or the section "memory management" [here](http://www.cs.hs-rm.de/~linn/fachsem0910/hirt/KVM.pdf) for a simpler read.

Comment: So I would allocate a ram drive the same way I would on bare metal? No special tricks required?

Comment: Correct.  (No special tricks that you need to do - thats all done by the Virtualisation system).   Most serious computing run heavily on VM's (abstraction allows control and increases resistance to failure), so its entirely reasonable to do..

Answer (score 1):

In actual testing,

- the VMWare ESXi 6.0 hostest Windows 8.1 guest operates at 300-1100MB/s

  - using a 100% reserved memory
- bare metal that's less powerful usually operates at 1000-3300MB/s

using [SQLIO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20163) testing at a variety of block sizes and outstanding IO counts, while using an [imDisk ramdisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk).

Comment: Your result is very interesting, although I wonder if there are other differences at play here due to different hardware ?.  According to http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2009/07/29/performance-impact-memory-effectiveness-of-virtualization.aspx, performance was about 83% of native in 2007 - before hardware optimizations had taken hold.